# Item cannot be found in the collection to the requested name or ordinal

Tags: datagrid, vb6, adodb

Upon clicking a client from the datagrid, all the clients informaition are loaded in the right side of the form, all seems to be doing pretty well.[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv5ZL.png][1]

and whenever I click the add payment button, it will open the payment form. 
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmznP.png][2]

but whenever I try to choose another client, it will produce a runtime error '3265'. and when I click the debug button, the fields to be filled seemed to have all the information they needed. Why is this error showing up? [https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuLg5.png][3]

Here is my code in loading all the clients

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Set Connect = New Class1
Set rx = New ADODB.Recordset

rx.Open "SELECT * FROM allclients ORDER by dateCreated ASC", con, 3, 3
lblLNumberRecords.Caption = Format(rx.RecordCount, "###,###,###.##")
Set DatCUSTOMERS.DataSource = rx

Me.Show

clearfields
End Sub
```

and here is my code when clicking a client:

```
Private Sub DatCUSTOMERS_RowColChange(LastRow As Variant, ByVal LastCol As Integer)

    Unload frmPaymentRecur

    lblID = rx.Fields("id")
    txtClientID = rx.Fields("clientCode")
    txtFirstName = rx.Fields("fname")
    txtLastName = rx.Fields("lname")
    txtMname = rx.Fields("mname")
    txtExtension = rx.Fields("extName")
    txtPin = rx.Fields("pinNo")
    txtDesignation = rx.Fields("designation")
    txtContactNo = rx.Fields("contactNo")
    txtAddress = rx.Fields("address")
    txtAge = rx.Fields("Age")
    txtSalary = rx.Fields("salary")
    cmbAssociation.Text = rx.Fields("fieldTypeTitle")
    cmbChoices.Text = rx.Fields("fieldNameTitle")
    cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    cmdAddLoan.Enabled = True
    cmdPayments.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```

here is my code when clicking the add payment button:

```
Private Sub cmdPayments_Click()
Dim flagClients, dateFlag, loanFlag As Integer
flagClients = 1
dateFlag = 1
loanFlag = 1

frmPaymentRecur.lbldateFlag.Caption = dateFlag
frmPaymentRecur.lblLoanFlag.Caption = loanFlag
frmPaymentRecur.txtClientID = rx.Fields("clientCode")
frmPaymentRecur.txtFolderNo = rx.Fields("folderCode")
frmPaymentRecur.txtFullName = rx.Fields("Name")
frmPaymentRecur.txtAssociation = rx.Fields("fieldNameTitle")
frmPaymentRecur.txtSalary = rx.Fields("salary")
frmPaymentRecur.CmbSelectPaymentType.Text = "All Loans"
frmPaymentRecur.lblFlag = flagClients

If rx.State = 1 Then rx.Close

rx.Open "SELECT DISTINCT(`Loan Type`) FROM paymentview WHERE `Client Code` = '" & Trim$(txtClientID.Caption) & "'", con, 3, 3

With rx
    Do While Not .EOF
        frmPaymentRecur.CmbSelectPaymentType.AddItem ![Loan Type]
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With

frmPaymentRecur.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Add Payment code, at the end, you are closing the `rx` recordset. It will be empty when you try updating your controls.

You've also populated the recordset with data form a different table, `paymentview`, where `id` probably doesn't exist.

You should create a separate recordset to handle your payment code instead of reusing the `rx` recordset.

Comment: it still produce that error even when i.erased the .close

Comment: the data in your `rx` is from `paymentview` table after you click `cmdPayments`

Comment: thank you so much, sir, the program is fixed, i followed your advise on using a different recordset, and it worked perfectly. thank you, sir.